# Advantages of using this.type in Scala?

Tags: scala

Here is an example from the stairway book:

```
object Example1 {

  import collection._

  class PrefixMap[T]
    extends mutable.Map[String, T]
    with mutable.MapLike[String, T, PrefixMap[T]] {
    var suffixes: immutable.Map[Char, PrefixMap[T]] = Map.empty
    var value: Option[T] = None

    def get(s: String): Option[T] = {
      // base case, you are at the root
      if (s.isEmpty) value
      // recursive
      else suffixes get (s(0)) flatMap (_.get(s substring 1))
    }

    def withPrefix(s: String): PrefixMap[T] = {
      if (s.isEmpty) this
      else {
        val leading = s(0)
        suffixes get leading match {
          case None => {
            // key does not exist, create it
            suffixes = suffixes + (leading -> empty)
          }
          case _ =>
        }
        // recursion
        suffixes(leading) withPrefix (s substring 1)
      }
    }

    override def update(s: String, elem: T) = {
      withPrefix(s).value = Some(elem)
    }

    override def remove(key: String): Option[T] = {
      if (key.isEmpty) {
        // base case. you are at the root
        val prev = value
        value = None
        prev
      } else {
        // recursive
        suffixes get key(0) flatMap (_.remove(key substring 1))
      }
    }

    def iterator: Iterator[(String, T)] = {
      (for (v <- value.iterator) yield ("", v)) ++
        (for ((chr, m) <- suffixes.iterator; (s, v) <- m.iterator) yield (chr +: s, v))
    }

    def +=(kv: (String, T)): this.type = {
      update(kv._1, kv._2)
      this
    }

    def -=(key: String): this.type = {
      remove(key)
      this
    }

    override def empty = new PrefixMap[T]
  }

}
```

Note that for the methods `+=` and `-=`, the return types are `this.type`. Can I use `PrefixMap[T]` here? If yes, what does `this.type` has to offer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use PrefixMap[T] here?

Yes.

> If yes, what does this.type has to offer?

For example, imagine you also have another class `PrefixMap2[T]` extending `PrefixMap`. Then with `this.type`, `+=` and `-=` called on a `PrefixMap2` will return itself (and therefore, a `PrefixMap2`); with `PrefixMap` return type, the compiler will only know they return a `PrefixMap`.

Comment: Nice. But how do you explain this `def withPrefix(s: String): PrefixMap[T]`?

Comment: What's to explain? It can't have `this.type`, because it doesn't always return `this`.